# mySQL: 1)single column name aliased 2) adding virtual column

Tags: mysql

Two questions:

1)

There are several tables that are used as an archive for other tables.
To do so, there is a

```
INSERT INTO data_archive_table (SELECT * FROM data_table)
```

The problem is that the `data_table.id` should be kept as `data_archive_table.old_id`.
Is there a way to write a query that will look like: `SELECT *, id AS old_id FROM data_table`, while the results columns will have ONLY the `old_data` column, and NOT the original `id` column?

Using all column names is the only option I see, but I prefer to avoid it.

2)

I want to add a virtual column named `deleted_time` to the insertion query, that will hold the current time.
Can it be done? if so - how ?(tutorials will be great)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

> 1.) You can use something like this query:

```
INSERT INTO data_archive_table
SELECT id AS old_id  -- be sure that data_archive_table has column oldID
       ,... -- You need to specify the names of the columns
FROM data_table
WHERE id = 'IDHERE' -- If you want to have condition.
```

> 2.) For this, you can add the value directly in you select statement

```
INSERT INTO `tableName`
SELECT colA,
       colB,
       , ...
       , NOW() as deleted_time -- NOW() is a function in MySQL
FROM `sourceTable`
WHERE colA = 'IDHERE' -- If you want to have condition.
```

[**NOW() in MySQL**](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_curdate.asp)

Comment: as to (2) - great! thanks. as to (1), maybe i wasn't clear enough.. i want to change only one column name without! using the other names.. using the *

Comment: @yossi i think you cannot do that because `asterisks` selects all column within the table, however you can do that only if `data_archive_table` has column `old_id` and `id`. By the way, it returns an error if you selected more column than the column  of the table you want to insert to.